# How to display last URL in UIWebView after the app has been terminated

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So what I need help with is to like make tabs. In which after the app is terminated then the user will be able to see the last URL they were at. But this code is not working.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] saveObject: [[request URL] absoluteString] forKey: @"SAVED-URL"];
}
```

Comment: When the user opens an URL store it in `NSUserDefaults`. Then load it when your app loads.

Comment: Can you give me some sample code please that would be so great. Thanks!

Comment: can you give me a source code. I have tried everything. Thanks!

Comment: No, you didnt try everything. You missed all basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the webview delegate to retrieve the last request.

`– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Save it eg. to the userdefaults like that:

`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] saveObject: [[request URL] absoluteString] forKey: @"SAVED-URL"];` 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

After the app restarted, load it again from the Userdefaults and load it up in the webview.

Comment: where do i implant this? better deatil please.

Comment: can you give me a source code. I have tried everything. Thanks!